# Reading from binary file into several labels on a form in C#

Tags: binary, writer

I'm writing a trivia game app in C# that writes data to a binary file, then reads the data from the file into six labels. The six labels are as follows:

lblQuestion    // This is where the question text goes.

lblPoints        // This is where the question points goes.

lblAnswerA    // This is where multiple choice answer A goes.

lblAnswerB    // This is where multiple choice answer B goes.

lblAnswerC    // This is where multiple choice answer C goes.

lblAnswerD    // This is where multiple choice answer D goes.

Here is the code for writing to the binary file:

```
{
            bw.Write(Question);
            bw.Write(Points);
            bw.Write(AnswerA);
            bw.Write(AnswerB);
            bw.Write(AnswerC);
            bw.Write(AnswerD);
}
```

Now for the code to read data from the file into the corresponding labels:

```
{
             FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName);
             BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
             lblQuestion.Text = br.ReadString();
             lblPoints.Text = br.ReadInt32() + " points";
             lblAnswerA.Text = br.ReadString();
             lblAnswerB.Text = br.ReadString();
             lblAnswerC.Text = br.ReadString();
             lblAnswerD.Text = br.ReadString();
}
```

The Question string reads correctly into lblQuestion.

The Points value reads correctly into lblPoints.

AnswerA, AnswerB, and AnswerC DO NOT read into lblAnswerA, lblAnswerB and lblAnswerC respectively.

lblAnswerD, however, gets the string meant for lblAnswerA.

Looking at the code for reading data into the labels, is there something missing, some sort of incremental value that needs to be inserted into the code in order to get the strings to the correct labels?

Comment: Try using Readline and WriteLine instead of ReadString and Write.  You don't need a BinaryReader; a StreamReader and StreamWriter will suffice.

Comment: Thanks, Harvey. I want to write the data to a file with a proprietary extension that I will create myself ( e.g. *.gam). Is it possible to do this while using StreamReader and StreamWriter?

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time and money.  You don't need BinaryWriter if you're just reading and writing text files.

Comment: Actually, I WILL need BinaryReader and BinaryWriter because I will eventually be writing and then reading an image file into the binary file. The binary file will have line after line of data-text and integers-followed by an image file. BTW, I can't find any code samples anywhere of how to write line-by-line using BinaryWriter. If I could find that, I'd be all set.

Comment: I would separate your text data from your binary data, putting them into separate files.  That way you can use the BinaryReader on the binary data, and the StreamReader on the text data.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Thanks!